# Implementing trig functions for dual numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm curious, how do common trig functions get implemented for dual numbers? One way would be to use the power series definition, but that seems inefficient

Comment: You mean the numbers of the form $a + b \varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon^2 = 0$? I never saw anything about it. Good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose $x=u+v\varepsilon$ where $u,v\in\mathbb C$ and $\varepsilon\ne0=\varepsilon^2$.
\begin{align}
\sin x & = x - \frac{x^3} 6 + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040} + \cdots \\[8pt]
& = (u+v\varepsilon) - \frac{u^3 + 3u^2 v\varepsilon}6 + \frac{u^5 + 5u^4 v\varepsilon}{120} - \frac{u^7+7u^6 v\varepsilon}{5040} + \cdots \tag 1 \\[8pt]
& = \sin u + v\varepsilon\left(1 - \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^4}{24} - \frac{u^6}{720} +\cdots\right) \\[8pt]
& = \sin u + v\varepsilon\cos u.
\end{align}
In $(1)$, I am simply applying the binomial theorem, and most of the terms vanish.

And so on $\ldots\ldots$

Power series are used here not for computing, but for establishing the trigonometric identity
$$
\sin(u + v\varepsilon) = \sin u + v\varepsilon\cos u
$$
whenever $\varepsilon$ is a non-zero object whose square is $0$ and there's enough commutativity.  For example, when you multiply matrices, they don't commute with each other but when you multiply a matrix by a scalar, those do.

Comment: It's rather beautiful what you've shown here. Intuitively, $\varepsilon$ is "small". In view of that intuition, note that $\cos(v \varepsilon) = 1$ and $\sin (v \varepsilon)=v \varepsilon$ therefore, the result you derive follows from the standard adding angles formula for sine.

Comment: That $\cos(v\varepsilon)=1$ and $\sin(v\varepsilon)=v\varepsilon$ follows from the power series as above, and then we can say $\sin(u+v\varepsilon)=\sin u\cos(v\varepsilon)+\cos u\sin(v\varepsilon)$ $=\sin u + v\varepsilon\cos u$.  To make everything rigorous, maybe we'd want to use power series to show that the identity for the sine of a sum applies to dual numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $\epsilon^2 = 0$ with $\epsilon \neq 0$, one can use Taylor expansion:

$$
f(a + b\epsilon) = f(a) + b\epsilon f'(a) 
$$

For trigonometric functions:

$$
\cos\left({a+b\epsilon}\right) = \cos{a} - b\epsilon\sin{a} \\
\sin\left({a+b\epsilon}\right) = \sin{a} + b\epsilon\cos{a} \\
\tan\left({a+b\epsilon}\right) = \tan{a} + b\epsilon\sec^2{a} \\
...\text{etc}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also start from the argument addition formulas and proceed by evaluating only 
$\sin (\epsilon) , \cos (\epsilon), \tan (\epsilon), \cot(\epsilon)$.
Then you can evaluate the functions from their Taylor expansions.
That is $\cos (\epsilon) = 1$, $\sin (\epsilon)= \epsilon$, $\tan (\epsilon)= \epsilon $ but $\cot (\epsilon)$ is undefined because $\epsilon$ does not have an inverse.