# How to calculate $\arcsin$ of dual number: $\arcsin\left( x+y\cdot\varepsilon\right)$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon\ne0=\varepsilon^{2}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, dual-numbers

How to calculate $\arcsin$ of dual number:
$\arcsin\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) = \dots$
where
$\begin{align*}
a, ~b &\in \mathbb{R}\\
\varepsilon^{2} &= 0\\
\varepsilon &\ne 0\\
\end{align*}$?

I recently saw the [question on SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/900581/1103878) where someone asked how to get $\sin$ from a dual number, so I had the idea of ​​reversing it, i.e. getting the $\arcsin$ from a dual number , to investigate.
For this I wanted to derive it myself, where several ideas would come to me on how to do it (via the [logarithm relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Extension_to_complex_plane), the [series expansion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html) and calculating backwards).
With the individual methods, however, I always came up with other solutions.
So I'm wondering what's correct, what I'm doing wrong and if there is a better method for this?

---

*I gave up on the logarithm method, since I would have to use the product of two imaginary units there, which, however, are not commutative with regard to multiplication, which would severely limit the validity of the formulas.*

###### My calculating backwards attempt

*I'm using the formula from this [SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/900581/1103878):*

$$
\begin{align*}
\sin\left( u + v \cdot \varepsilon \right) &= \sin\left( u \right) + v \cdot \cos\left( u \right) \cdot \varepsilon\\
\sin\left( u + v \cdot \varepsilon \right) &= x + y \cdot \varepsilon\\
\\
x = \sin\left( u \right) &\wedge y = v \cdot \cos\left( u \right)\\
\arcsin\left( x \right) = u &\wedge y = v \cdot \cos\left( \arcsin\left( x \right) \right)\\
\arcsin\left( x \right) = u &\wedge y = v \cdot \cos\left( \arcsin\left( x \right) \right)\\
\arcsin\left( x \right) = u &\wedge y = v \cdot \sqrt{1 - x^{2}}\\
\arcsin\left( x \right) = u &\wedge \frac{y}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}} = v\\
\\
\sin\left( \arcsin\left( x \right) + \frac{y}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}} \cdot \varepsilon \right) &= x + y \cdot \varepsilon\\
\arcsin\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) &= \arcsin\left( x \right) + \frac{y}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}} \cdot \varepsilon\\
\end{align*}
$$

And this can only be true for $\left| x \right| < 1$ which I find strange since I didn't expact that $\left| x \right| = 1$ gets lost as a possible argument.

---

###### My series expansion attempt

$$
\begin{align*}
\arcsin\left( z \right) &=  z + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \cdot \frac{z^{3}}{3} + \left( \frac{1 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 4} \right) \cdot \frac{z^{5}}{5} + \left( \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6} \right) \cdot \frac{z^{7}}{7} + \cdots\\
\arcsin\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) &=  \left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \cdot \frac{\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{3}}{3} + \left( \frac{1 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 4} \right) \cdot \frac{\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{5}}{5} + \left( \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6} \right) \cdot \frac{\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right)^{7}}{7} + \cdots\\
\arcsin\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) &=  x + y \cdot \varepsilon + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \cdot \frac{x^{3} + 3 \cdot x^{2} \cdot y \cdot \varepsilon}{3} + \left( \frac{1 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 4} \right) \cdot \frac{x^{5} + 5 \cdot x^{4} \cdot y \cdot \varepsilon}{5} + \left( \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6} \right) \cdot \frac{x^{7} + 7 \cdot x^{6} \cdot y \cdot \varepsilon}{7} + \cdots\\
\arcsin\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) &=  \arcsin\left( x \right) + \left( 1 + x^{2} + x^{4} + x^{6}  + \cdots \right) \cdot y \cdot \varepsilon\\
\arcsin\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) &=  \arcsin\left( x \right) + \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^{2 \cdot k} \right) \cdot y \cdot \varepsilon\\
\arcsin\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) &=  \arcsin\left( x \right) + \frac{1}{1 - x^{2}} \cdot y \cdot \varepsilon, \text{ for } \left| x \right| < 1\\
\arcsin\left( x + y \cdot \varepsilon \right) &=  \arcsin\left( x \right) + \frac{y}{1 - x^{2}} \cdot \varepsilon, \text{ for } \left| x \right| < 1\\
\end{align*}
$$

But obviously something is wrong:
$$ \arcsin\left( x \right) + \frac{y}{1 - x^{2}} \cdot \varepsilon \ne \arcsin\left( x \right) + \frac{y}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}} \cdot \varepsilon$$

Comment: You lost important rational coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Automatic differentiation" is the way to go. Namely, for any real-analytic function $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, its natural extension to $\Bbb R\oplus \Bbb R \varepsilon$ in fact satisfies $$f(x+y\varepsilon) = f(x) + yf'(x)\varepsilon,$$for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$. To see this, write $$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{6} x^3+\cdots$$and replace $x\mapsto x+y\varepsilon$, noting that $$(x+y\varepsilon)^n = x^n + nx^{n-1}y\varepsilon$$for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$, to obtain $$\begin{align} f(x+y\varepsilon) &= f(0) + f'(0)(x+y\varepsilon) + \frac{f''(0)}{2}(x^2+2xy\varepsilon) + \frac{f'''(0)}{6}(x^3+3x^2y\varepsilon) + \cdots \\ &= f(0) + f'(0) x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{6}x^3+\cdots  \\ &\qquad + y\varepsilon\left(f'(0) + f''(0)x + \frac{f'''(0)}{2}x^2+\cdots\right) \\ &= f(x) + yf'(x)\varepsilon.\end{align}$$
Taking $f = \arcsin$, we have that $$\arcsin(x+y\varepsilon) = \arcsin(x) + \frac{y\varepsilon}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$Trying to do this calculation with $\arcsin$ instead of an abstract $f$ turns out to be a distraction.